# Swift Spritekit physicsBodies do collision bit masks in the SKScene editor

Tags: swift, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have two balls. I don't want them to collide with each other. I want them to collide with everything else. I made the two balls have different category bit masks of 2 and 3. All the other objects have the same category bit mask of 1. I have tried setting the collision bit masks of both balls to 1. I also read something that said that an operation is done to the collision bit mask and the category bit mask and if it is nonzero then there is a collision, so I made the balls have the collision bit mask as the category bit mask of the other. So they would be 0 and everything else would be nonzero and collide. None of this works, so how do I actually make them so it works the way I want them to.

[image]

[image]

These are some of the masks I tried

Answer (score 0):

Do it in code, it's so much easier to read.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  weak var ball1: SKSpriteNode?
  weak var ball2: SKSpriteNode?

  let noCategory:UInt32 = 0
  let ball1Category:UInt32 = 0b1
  let ball2Category:UInt32 = 0b1 << 1
  let wall1Category:UInt32 = 0b1 << 2

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
      ball1 = self.childNode(withName: "ball1") as? SKSpriteNode
      ball2 = self.childNode(withName: "ball2") as? SKSpriteNode
      wall1 = self.childNode(withName: "wall1") as? SKSpriteNode

      ball1?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ball1Category
      ball1?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noCategory

      ball2?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ball2Category
      ball2?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noCategory

      wall1?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wall1Category
      wall1?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ball1Category | ball2Category
  }
}
```

Now you can easily see that wall1 collides with the ball1 and ball2 but the balls themselves don't collide with anything. With collisions only one of the physicsbodies needs to have the collisionbitmask set. Therefore you could add the ball1 and ball2Category to all physicsbodies collisionbitmasks except the opposite ball and the balls with collide with those physicsbodies but not each other.

Comment: is there a way to assign a category bit mask created in code in the skscene editor because i have many objects that i dont want to have to retrieve all of them to add the categpry bit mask in code

Comment: @JoeBob123 create a node in the sks and get it in the code to act as a model (clone it when you need another instance). Observe the way the template "game" does this with the "label" and the "spinny node" for example.